# Flask/Python: How can I render error pages from a directory?

Tags: python, flask, http-error

I have a directory in my flask app called `error`. This directory contains HTML documents named after error codes (without file extensions).
Whenever an Error happens I want to return the corresponding HTML file if it exists and render a template from `error/template` if it doesn't exist.
I already tried using `@app.errorhandler(Exception)` but it was never called (I used a print statement to test that).

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the `error_handler` without a decorator.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

def handle_handler(e):
    code = 500
    if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        code = e.code
    return render_template("error.html", error_code=code), code

app = Flask('test')
app.config['TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS']=True
app.register_error_handler(Exception, default_handler)
```